# How do you install package on a build without solution file?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

We have a teamcity server (v8) for building / deploying our web app.

For a build we don't have a solution file (sln), only a csproj (and the packages.config). But teamcity asks for a sln file on a nuget installer step.
How can we do ?

note : we have a sln file but it's common to all our web projects (~10) and not included on the checkout rules (for building one site we create a checkout rule including only the desired website and the library common to all of them).

Comment: You could use a command line step and use nuget via the command line? This would let you work with projects rather than solutions. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Alternatively you could create extra solution files and only reference the relevant subsets of projects.

Comment: I did it with a command line, the only problem beeing that I don't have a nuget package tab on my build.